# Verify whether row and column names are the same between matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

Say I have matrices one and two:

```
    > one <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3, dimnames=list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A", "B", "C")))
    > one
      A B C
    X 1 4 7
    Y 2 5 8
    Z 3 6 9
    > two <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3, dimnames=list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("WRONG", "B", "C")))
    > two
      WRONG B C
    X     1 4 7
    Y     2 5 8
    Z     3 6 9
```

Is there a command that can produce a logical value to verify whether the column and row names of matrix one are the same as those in matrix two?

Comment: If one of the answers below has worked for you, please consider clicking the gray check-mark  to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `identical()`.  For row names -

```
identical(rownames(one), rownames(two))
# [1] TRUE
```

And the same for `colnames()`.  For all `dimnames()`, same thing -

```
identical(dimnames(one), dimnames(two))
# [1] FALSE
```

For row and column individually at the same time -

```
Map(identical, dimnames(one), dimnames(two))
# [[1]]
# [1] TRUE
#
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE
```

**Update:** In response to your comment, for multiple matrices you may try

```
length(unique(lapply(list(one, two, three), dimnames))) == 1
```

If this returns `FALSE`, you know that at least one set of `dimnames` is different.

Comment: For extra upvotes, chaining: `library(magrittr); list(one,two) %>% lapply(dimnames) %>% Reduce("identical",.)`

Comment: Well, at least it should stave off a second answer with chains :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I wanted to compare more than two matrices, is there an easier method than comparing all two by two?

Comment: @E.Mun - I think `length(unique(lapply(list(one, two, three), dimnames))) == 1` would work for that.  If it is `FALSE` you know that at least one set of `dimnames` is different

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need to identify this for each row and column, you could do this

```
cbind(unlist(dimnames(one)), unlist(dimnames(one)) %in% unlist(dimnames(two)))

#     [,1] [,2]   
#row1 "X"  "TRUE" 
#row2 "Y"  "TRUE" 
#row3 "Z"  "TRUE" 
#col1 "A"  "FALSE"
#col2 "B"  "TRUE" 
#col3 "C"  "TRUE"
```

Or else another alternative would be

```
do.call(`%in%`, list(dimnames(one), dimnames(two)))

#for row and column seperately
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```